Shabbos as a kaparah for Mechiras Yosef
Zera Shimshon on Miketz in Derush 1 brings down Zohar Chadash 49b, also Zohar on Parasha Ki Sisa 73b that Shmiras Shabbos was given as a kapara for mechiras Yosef. Could one please explain if one has learned it? Thank you.

Explanation I heard is as follows.
In Parshas V'eschanan it says
וזכרת כי עבד היית בארץ מצרים ויפדך ה' אלקיך משם ביד חזקה
ובזרוע נטויה, על כן צוך ה' אלקיך לעשות את יום השבת,
The Torah tells us that Yosef that was sold as a slave to Egypt, and therefore there was servitude in Egypt, and as forgiveness for this sin keep Shabbos.
The Chanukas HaTorah "Os 178" says that for this reason we have Lechem Mishna on Shabbos as the Gematria of two times Lechem לחם = Yosef יוסף.
